# Remove a function along with all callbacks/functions in it

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to remove a function and also remove all the callbacks/functions that are inside of it?

Example:

```js
var myFunction = function() {

  thisFunctionHasACallback(function() {

    alert( "I was called!" );

  });

};

myFunction();

myFunction = undefined;
```

Even if I unset `myFunction`, the callback for `thisFunctionHasACallback` will still activate when called.

Comment: You'd have to track down all the places where a reference to that inner function is saved. So, basically, **no**.

Comment: Sure, `thisFunctionHasACallback` is declared somewhere else. It is not a callback function, it's just function invocation.

Comment: *sigh* why is this not a thing :/

Comment: Please show a case where the callback defined within `myFunction` executes when calling `thisFunctionHasACallback` somewhere outside of that function.

Comment: @Teemu clearly if `myFunction()` set up a timer or event handler is what the OP is talking about.

Comment: @Pointy Possibly, but I'd like to see it in the question, it doesn't make much sense otherwise.

Comment: If I unset the function, everything stops executing except for the contents of the callback from thisFunctionHasACallback, so it still pops up with an alert. I can go make a fancy handler for this, but is there just no catch-all method like I thought it would with unsetting the entire function?

Comment: That's just not how JavaScript (and languages like it) work. You can't really "delete" objects of any sort; all you can do is overwrite references to them (which is what you're doing to the `myFunction` symbol). That doesn't directly affect the former value, it just gives the symbol a new value (`undefined`).

Comment: Oh well, thanks for helping out. Guess I will have to come up with a different solution.

Comment: If you really want to do something like this, I suppose you could try something along these lines: `var switch = true; var myFunction = function() { if (switch) {

  thisFunctionHasACallback(function() {

    alert( "I was called!" );

  }); }

};

myFunction();

switch = false;`; now I think that anywhere you call myFunction from, the myFunction should still have a reference to the same switch. But this seems really hacky; not sure why you're trying to unset a function in the first place.

Comment: I am creating a one-page application, it loads CSS, HTML and JS from the server for each section of the page. Once the user goes to another section, I need to unload the previous section so that if the user visits that section again stuff won't execute twice.